# Angular no envía el valor de un input al autocompletar - ReactiveForms

Tags: angular

a ver si me podéis ayudar un poquito :P

Tengo un formulario donde se autor rellenan campos según vas completando otros, el caso es que al ejecutar el submit no me devuelve ningún valor en los campos que se han auto completado.

He preparado un pequeño ejemplo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4aaq5 donde pueden ver en la consola que no devuelve nada "undefined"

Mi componente html:

```html
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit( f )" #f="ngForm">
  <input name="test" [(ngModel)]="test" />
  <input [value]="test" name="test2" [(ngModel)]="test2"/>
  <button type="submit">get data</button>
  <p>{{formData | json}}</p>
</form>
```

Mi componente ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  formData;
  onSubmit( form: NgForm ) {
    this.formData = form.value;
    console.log(form.value);
  }
}
```

On Submit:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias de ante mano!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que en lugar de simplemente adjuntar un link, pongas el código que creas relevante en tu pregunta , ya que así le da un aspecto mejor y evitas posibles problemas si el enlace no funciona/no es accesible.

Comment: Ok! gracias! ya he puesto lo básico, por eso no puse nada, pero tienes razón con lo del link :)

Comment: Te recomendaría crear el formGroup de manera programática

Comment: Antes de agregar una respuesta, queria saber si era posible que agregues un ejemplo real de lo que necesitas, si el caso que necesitas es el exacto que expones, te recomiendo al igual que @PabloLozano crear el `formGroup` en el componente y agregar evento ´change´

Comment: El problema esta en que solo le estas dando el `value` al `input2` pero no le estas setieando el modelo, si cambias la variable `<input [value]="test" name="test2" [(ngModel)]="test2"/>` por `<input [value]="test" name="test2" [(ngModel)]="test"/>` observaras que de primera cambia y envia el valor, aun que te aconsejo crear un **FormGroup** para que al escribir en un campo no remplaze el valor del segundo.

Comment: Gracias a todos! el caso que tengo @sioesi, es: Utilizo Google place para auto rellenar campos como latitud, long, ciudad, etc...  meto los valores que me devuelven en inputs con hidden para así mandarlos a mi servicio con el formulario. Probaré lo de formGroup! gracias!! :)

Comment: Entonces la solución del input hidden esta demás, podrías simplemente obtener el valor y guardarlo en algún objeto dentro de tu componente, @JulianChabrillon Saludos!

Comment: Si @sioesi, el tema es que lo quería hacer así porque lo necesito en otro componente donde no lo oculto y no tener que guardarlo en algún objeto, pero si que es verdad que creo es la mejor opción! Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de los consejos que me habéis dado respecto a utilizar formGroup, he dado con la solución a mi problema:

He dejado un ejemplo básico en https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4aaq5

Ahora mi component.ts es:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormGroup, FormControl,  FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  name = 'Angular';
  formData;
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  test: "";
  test2: "";
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.myGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            test: '',
            test2: '',
        });
    }
      onAmountChange(event) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
    const amount = event.currentTarget.value;
    this.myGroup.controls['test2'].setValue(amount);
  }
  onSubmit( form: NgForm ) {
    this.formData = this.myGroup.value;
    console.log(this.myGroup.value);
  }
}
```

Y mi HTML

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit( f )" [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input name="test" (keyup)="onAmountChange($event)" formControlName="test" />
  <input  name="test2" formControlName="test2"/>
  <button type="submit">get data</button>
  <p>{{formData | json}}</p>
</form>
```

GRACIAS a todos por la ayuda! :)